# XAMPP - Error establishing a database connection after changing port

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp

MySQL shut down unexpectedly on **XAMPP**. Then I changed the port number 3306 to 3307 to both my.ini and config.inc.php file.

Now MySQL is running and localhost/phpmyadmin/ also running.

But my WordPress website not showing. The problem is -

**Error establishing a database connection**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I think the problem not from Mysql it might be Database. Did you create Database correctly and connected it to your WordPress website just double check.

Comment: Everything was fine. I could login and customize the WordPress website. But I face this problem when I change MySQL port

Comment: So why you change port?

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour Because MySQL shut down unexpectedly on XAMPP

Comment: To solve the problem of "MySQL shut down unexpectedly on XAMPP". You might want to start as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've forgot to change MySQL port in the `wp-config.php` file in your WordPress website folder.

Comment: Where to change?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wo3fhJT4-JDq5Q_QmlnabAYFPyGCV59C/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MDSayfulIslam I think like that `/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307' );`

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour But it automatically redirects to install.php and tells me to install WordPress anew.

Comment: @MDSayfulIslam Change debug to true like this `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
`